# Find all occurence of a pattern in a string using bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to get all the character sequence which match a particular pattern in a string using bash.

**Example 1:**

```
Input:
Some random prefix "characters inside quotes".fixed() some random postfix  
Output:
characters inside quotes
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input:
Some random prefix "characters inside quotes first".fixed() some random postfix, some random post prefix "characters inside quotes second".fixed() some random post postfix.  
Output:  
characters inside quotes first  
characters inside quotes second
```

I'm using this script:

```
input='Some random prefix "characters inside quotes".fixed() some random postfix'
pattern=".* \"(.*)\".fixed()"
[[ $input =~ $pattern ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This works perfectly for Example 1 but not for Example 2. What should i do to generate the correct output for Example 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `[[ $input =~ $pattern ]]` only matches first occurrence in the string. You need to use `grep` or other tools to get multiple matches from a string.

For example, with `pcregrep`, you can use:

```sh
input='Some random prefix "characters inside quotes".fixed() some random postfix'
pcregrep -o1 '"([^"]*)"' <<< "$input"
## => characters inside quotes first
##    characters inside quotes second
```

*Details*:

- `-o1` - output mode on, print capturing group #1 value(s) if match found
- `"([^"]*)"` - a regex that matches a `"`, then captures any zero or more chars other than `"` into Group 1 and then a `"` is matched.

With `grep`/`sed`:

```sh
grep -o '"[^"]*"' <<< "$input" | sed -E 's/^"|"$//g'
## => characters inside quotes first
##    characters inside quotes second
```

With `"[^"]*"` regex, you match all occurrences of the pattern, then with `sed`, you remove a double quotation mark at the start and end of each match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation along with the solution. Works with both `pcregrep` and `grep`/`sed`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure Bash solution without external tool:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input='Input: Some random prefix "characters inside quotes first".fixed() some random postfix, some random post prefix "characters inside quotes second".fixed() some random post postfix.'
pattern='(.*)\"(.*)\"\.fixed\(\)'

matches=()

while [[ $input =~ $pattern ]]; do
  matches=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${matches[@]}")
  input="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done

for match in "${matches[@]}"; do
  printf %s\\n "$match"
done
```

Output:

```
characters inside quotes first
characters inside quotes second
```

Can also be done without reversing the matches with a different pattern for the captured text between quotes:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input='Input: Some random prefix "characters inside quotes first".fixed() some random postfix, some random post prefix "characters inside quotes second".fixed() some random post postfix.'
pattern='\"([^"]*)\"\.fixed\(\)(.*)'

while [[ $input =~ $pattern ]]; do
  printf %s\\n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  input="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```